# When can the gauge of wire change in a household circuit?

Tags: wiring

Normally in a pigtail, you are suppose to have the same gauge of copper wires from that receptacle which would go to that one particular circuit breaker. Are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Same gauge where? You can change gauge in a circuit if you start out with a larger gauge to reduce voltage drop, for example. Please edit your post to ask something more specific, say about your particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

Pigtails are referred to as tap conductors in the NEC.

Unlike tap conductors for some luminaries, ovens, and other appliances, which can be smaller than the OCPD, it is not permitted to use a smaller tap for general wall receptacle outlets.

`NEC 2014 210.19 (A)(4)(Exception C) Individual outlets, **other than receptacle outlets**, with taps not over 450 mm (18 in.) long.`

Here's a good example of tap conductors on a dimmer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can always use a larger wire with a smaller breaker, but not the reverse. What that means in terms of your question is, you can transition to a smaller wire if the OCPD (breaker, fuse, etc.) does not have a greater ampacity limit than the smaller wire.

As an example, if I run some 12AWG from a 15A breaker, then pigtail into 14AWG, it's fine. If I run 10AWG from a 20A breaker, then pigtail into 14AWG, it's not fine.

Comment: I guess it's not really a pigtail, but it's clearly ok to have a smaller-gauge wire as the leads on a fixture.

Comment: @RustyShackleford -- those, like appliance cords, are protected by the fixture's listing, basically

Comment: I just installed a tankless water heater, which is on a 20A circuit, but the hardwired leads coming from it are 18AWG. I don't know of a 5A breaker, and as @ThreePhaseEel said, the unit itself is listed in such a way that it's acceptable.

Comment: Wow, that's mighty low power for a tankless.

Comment: @RustyShackleford I should have clarified, it's a 150kBTU, natural gas tankless requiring electrical power for an ignition and control board.